# Desktop GLSL without ftransform()

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I'm porting a codebase of mine from fixed-function OpenGL 1.x to OpenGL 2.x - Technically OpenGL ES 2.0, but I'm still coding on the desktop, just keeping in mind the limitations that ES 2.0 imposes which are similar to the 3.1 'new' profile.

Problem is, it seems like for anything other than 2D, creating a shader passing in the modelviewprojection matrix as a uniform does not work. Normally I get a black screen, but if I set the Z value of all my vertices to 0 I get stuff to show up.

Putting my shaders in RenderMonkey works when I have ES 2.0 mode enabled, but on standard desktop GL it's just a black screen (no compiler errors/warnings):

vert shader:

```
uniform mat4 mvp_matrix;
uniform mat4 obj_matrix;
uniform vec4 u_color;
attribute vec3 a_vertex;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord0;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texcoord0;

void main(void)
{
   v_color = u_color;
   gl_Position = mvp_matrix * (obj_matrix * vec4(a_vertex, 1.0));
   v_texcoord0 = a_texcoord0;
}
```

frag shader:

```
uniform sampler2D t_texture0;
varying vec2 v_texcoord0;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main(void)
{
   vec4 color = texture2D(t_texture0, v_texcoord0);
   gl_FragColor = color * v_color;
}
```

I am passing in the matrices as glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, mvpMatrix);
This shader works like gold for anything drawn in 2D. What am I doing wrong here? Or am I *required* to use ftransform() on desktop GL?

Comment: What is "objMatrix" and how does it differ from "mvpMatrix"? What is the contents of these matrices?

Comment: objMatrix is the local transform of whatever's been drawn, while mvpMatrix contains the transform for the camera(modelview) and the projection matrix (model * proj). In my particular testing, I've been leaving the objMatrix set to Identity. Transformations using all of these matrices also work just fine in 2D when the projection is set to my glOrtho replacement. But the big question is, I'm curious as to why this shader works in RenderMonkey set on ES 2.0 mode, but not on desktop (and there are no compiler errors or warnings, either). I'm thinking this is the source of my problem.

Comment: P.S. I have also exported a valid model & proj matrix from the old OpenGL 1.1 version of my app and dumped it straight into the OpenGL ES 2.x version, and still nothing appears. Makes me even more certain it's either an issue with the shader, or passing the matrices to the shader.

Answer (score 6):

One thing I think needs a bit of clarification:

- A model matrix transforms an object from object coordinates to world coordinates.
- A view matrix transforms the world coordinates to eye coordinates.
- A projection matrix converts eye coordinates to clip coordinates.

Based on standard naming conventions, the mvpMatrix is projection * view * model, in that order. There is no other matrices that you need to multiply by. Projection is your projection matrix (either ortho or perspective), view is the camera transform matrix (NOT the modelview), and model is the position, scale, and rotation of your object.

I believe the issue either lies in either multiplying matrices that don't need to be multiplied together or in multiplying matrices in the wrong order. (matrix multiplication isn't commutative)

If you haven't already solved this, I would recommend sending all 3 matrices over separately and later dumping the values back to make sure there are no issues sending the matrices over.

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_vertex;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord0;

varying vec2 v_texcoord0;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

void main(void)
{
   gl_Position = projection * view * model * a_vertex;
   v_texcoord0 = a_texcoord0;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
uniform sampler2D t_texture0;
uniform vec4 u_color;

varying vec2 v_texcoord0;

void main(void)
{
   vec4 color = texture2D(t_texture0, v_texcoord0);
   gl_FragColor = color * u_color;
}
```

Also I moved the color uniform to the frag shader, passing it through as a varying is unnecessary when all the vertices will have the same color.